# Does materialized view data in sybase 16 get cleared after database server reboot

Tags: sybase, materialized-views

I have Sybase 16 server in my local machine. I have created materialized views for some intermediate tables to improve performance. I have the setting for the view as 'IMMEDIATE REFRESH' so that the view is updated when the underlying tables are updated.

Since materialized views physically store the data, if I reboot my local machine will the data get cleared? If yes, then when will the data for the view get reloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Data in materialized views is persistently stored, so not affected by an ASE reboot.